# Преобразовать строку в дату посредством системной функции

Tags: дата, java, синтаксический-анализ

Всем здравствуйте.

Имеется строка с датой такого вида: "31.05.2010 00:00:00", хочу преобразовать ее к виду MySQL-левскому: "2010-05-31 00:00:00".
Имеется ли какая-нибудь функция для простого преобразования? Или придется ковырять эту строку, заменять точки на тире и переставлять значения?

Попытался сделать так:

```
String str = "31.05.2010 00:00:00";
SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
String str2 = dateFormat.format(str);
```

Получил экзепшн ) Есть ли какой-то простой способ? Потому как это не единичный случай преобразования, даты будут и других форматов приходить.

Заранее спасибо!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Сохраняете свою дату в date, потом ее парсите в новую дату (в нужном формате):

```
    String str = "31.05.2010 00:00:00";
    Date realDate = new SimpleDateFormat("dd.mm.yyyy HH:mm:ss", Locale.US).parse(str);
    String str2= new SimpleDateFormat("dd-mm-yyyy HH:mm:ss", Locale.US).format(realDate);
```

Comment: Не помогло ( тот же самый экзепшн

String date = "31.05.2010 00:00:00";
Date newDate = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss").parse(date);

Comment: Сейчас гляну, может, я что-то перепутал.
__

Исправил, смотрите.

Comment: Cooler, большое Вам спасибо! Все работает. Вы избавили меня от лишней траты времени.

Comment: Пожалуйста)